# Comparing values: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c, random, lvalue

Why can't I compare the results of the random function?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main (){

srand(time(NULL));

/*Player 1*/
int P1d1, P1d2, P1total;
P1d1 = 1 + rand() % 6;  //Rolls Player 1's first die; random # between 1-6
P1d2 = 1 + rand() % 6;  //Rolls Player 1's second die; random # between 1-6
P1total = P1d1 + P1d2;  //Takes total of both rolls

/*Player 2*/
int P2d1, P2d2, P2total;
P2d1 = 1 + rand() % 6; //Rolls Player 2's first die; random # between 1-6
P2d2 = 1 + rand() % 6; //Rolls Player 2's second die; random # between 1-6
P2total = P2d1 + P2d2; //Takes total of both rolls

if (P1d1 == P1d2 && P2d1 =! P2d2){ <--- ERROR HERE
    printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
    }
else if (P2d1 == P2d2 && P1d1 =! P1d2) {
    printf("Player 2 wins!\n");
    }
}
```

I get the error message `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`.

I understand that this means the left-hand side of the assignment has to be a variable, but the left-hand side *is* a variable (int P1d1). Any suggestions?

Comment: Because it should be `==`, not `=`.

Comment: It still gives the same error message with    ==

Comment: It's != not =!  And this is long enough

Comment: I would vote to close as this has nothing to do with Rand()  and is unlikely to help anyone in the future. But I don't know the right close reason.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm sure that it's a duplicate of the same stupid lazy mistake, and it also lacks a minimal understanding -- choose your poison.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: this shouldn't be closed because the asker has clearly done there own research and become stuck. I'd vote to modify the question name to be something to do with the problem "Problem comparing values: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>You probably need to use `==` (equality) rather than `=` (assignment). I see you've changed that in your question.</strike>

The cause of the error message is:

```
P2d1 =! P2d2
```

The inequality operator is `!=`, not `=!`.

The way you're written it, it's an assignment `=` followed by a unary "not" `!`. And since `=` has very low precedence, this:

```
(P1d1 == P1d2 && P2d1 =! P2d2)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
((P1d1 == P1d2 && P2d1) = !P2d2)
```

and of course `(P1d1 == P1d2 && P2d1)` is not a valid target for an assignment.

This is one of the more *ahem* **interesting** things about programming in C. In some languages, a minor typo is likely to introduce a syntax error, and the compiler's error message is likely to tell you exactly what the problem is. In C, minor typos can easily result in code that's still syntactically correct, but that has some absurd meaning -- or, in your case, that produces an error message that's not very illuminating.

A good approach, if you don't understand what a compiler error message means, is to ignore what it says and just look carefully at the earliest line of code that the compiler complains about.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is an assignment operator.
`==` is a comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!=`.

```
if (P1d1 == P1d2 && P2d1 =! P2d2){
printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
}
```

is the same as

```
if ((P1d1 == P1d2 && P2d1) = (!(P2d2))){
printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
}
```